# Devolver un queryset a partir de datos del request

Tags: python, django

**Tengo el siguiente modelo:**

```
class Actividad(models.Model):
    nombre = models.TextField()
    es_principal = model.BooleanField()
    fecha_inicio = DateField()
    fecha_fin = DateField()
    dirigente = TextField()
```

**Y este es su viewset:**

```
class ActividadViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ActividadSerializer
    queryset = Actividad.objects.all()
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, es un `viewset` básico de `Django Restframework` y cuando se realiza una petición **GET** devuelvo todas las actividades.

Ahora necesito filtrar las actividades a partir de los datos que vengan en el **request.data**. Por ejemplo si lo que piden es las actividades según el nombre o la fecha de inicio:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Actividad.objects.all()
    nombre = self.request.query_params.get('nombre')
    fecha_inicio = self.request.query_params.get('fecha_inicio')
    if nombre:
        queryset = queryset.filter('nombre' = nombre)
    elif:
        queryset = queryset.filter('fecha_inicio' = fecha_inicio)
    return queryset
```

Mi duda es cómo construir el `queryset` para varios casos.

**Por ejemplo:**

- Devolver las actividades según el nombre (listo)
- Devolver las actividades según la fecha de inicio (listo)
- Devolver las actividades según nombre, fecha de inicio y fecha de fin
- Devolver las actividades según nombre, fecha de inicio, fecha fin y
  si es principal
- Devolver las actividades según fecha inicio, fecha fin y si es
  principal
- Devolver las actividades según fecha de inicio y fecha de fin

En otro lenguaje yo hubiese utilizado un `switch-case` pero eso no existe en `Python`. Tengo que hacer un **if** por cada una de las condiciones de la lista anterior o hay alguna forma "dinámica" de construir el `queryset`? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero te sirva amigo

```
def get_queryset(self):
"""se reciven las variables y las almacenas"""

    nombre = self.request.query_params.get('nombre')
    es_principal = self.request.query_params.get('es_principal')
    fecha_inicio = self.request.query_params.get('fecha_inicio')
    fecha_fin = self.request.query_params.get('fecha_fin')
    dirigente = self.request.query_params.get('dirigente')

    # a las variables almacenadas las guardadas en un diccionario 
    my_filter = {}

    if nombre:
        my_filter["nombre"] = nombre

    if es_principal:
        my_filter["es_principal"] = es_principal

    if fecha_inicio:        
        my_filter["fecha_inicio"] = fecha_inicio

    if fecha_fin:
        my_filter["fecha_fin"] = fecha_fin

    if dirigente:
        my_filter["dirigente"] = dirigente

    # aca creas el query-set y pasas tu diccionario
    queryset = Actividad.objects.filter(**my_filter)

    #retornas el resultado del query-set
    return queryset

##fin
```

Comment: Exactamente lo que buscaba, gracias!