# Como enviar datos en una peticion GET al hacer test unitarios en Django?

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Estoy trabajando en el backend de una aplicacion web usando Django y Django Restframework. Tengo definidos varios viewsets de acuerdo a los modelos que se manejan y a los cuales se les realizan varias peticiones (**GET, PUT, DELETE, POST**).

He hecho varios test unitarios para comprobar que las peticiones devuelven los valores adecuados y hasta ahora todo marcha bien. Hace unos dias hice [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/132254/devolver-un-queryset-a-partir-de-datos-del-request/) para saber como extraer informacion del request, y ahora quiero hacer un test donde yo envie dicha informacion en el request. Como puedo hacerlo?

Gracias de antemano y perdon por la ortografia.

Comment: Estas usando el testing de django o algo como coverage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu pregunta tiene poco detalle, a priori puedo darte una solución muy general.
Podrías usar `django.test.Client` para hacer requests:

```
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> c = Client()
>>> response = c.get('/customers/details/', {'name': 'fred', 'age': 7})
```

Luego deberías hacer una serie de asserts para chequear la respuesta retornada por el server.
Para más info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#making-requests

Comment: Hola, yo utilizo el APIClient de restframework.test. Gracias a tu respuesta me fije en que el client.get(...) tiene un parametro llamado data donde le paso la informacion que quiero comprobar, muy similar a lo que me has sugerido. Gracias!